# Likens the background color of the label and the sheet column

Tags: excel, vba

How to write code for the background color of a label with the color source of the color cells. for example:

```
Cmb.backcolor=sheets("sheet1").cells(2,2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
Label1.BackColor = sheets("sheet1").cells(2,2).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in using cell object, then you can try -
'Using Cell Object
Cells(3, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 5 ' 5 indicates Blue Color

Alternatively, if you are familiar with Range object, then you can try -
'Using Range Object
Range("B3").Interior.ColorIndex = 5

You can also write the same code using RGB as follows :
'Using Cell Object
Cells(3, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 250)
'Using Range Object
Range("B3").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 250)

Hope you find this Helpful.

Comment: What if I want to apply it to the background of a form label? Like the code I wrote above